# Eclipse C++. Included .h files with classes. "Symbol '[class]' could not be resolved"

Tags: c++, eclipse, class, include

I have two .h files: List.h which contains struct Node and Linked list class, and SkipList.h which includes "List.h", has a class SkipList defined and uses a instances of classes from List.h.
I'm using Eclipse IDE. These source compile with g++ from the terminal, but in Eclipse it gives me errors in SkipList.h file, that "Symbol 'Node' could not be resolved" and "Symbol 'LinkedList' could not be resolved".
Can somebody please tell me what do you think that could be the problem?

Reedited: I've posted a code when I had the problem, but I had to erase the link because it's part of a college homework, and I don't want to risk to much into other colleagues finding my work and copying it, not that is any master piece :))

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined Node as a member of List? Have you defined Node and ListNode in a namespace that isn't used in SkipList? Have you tried to import your include files with angle brackets without adding the relevant path to the project include paths?

Basically, unless you present some relevant sample code with which we can replicate the error, there's probably not a lot that can be said to answer your question.

(That said, in my experience Eclipse is *very* flaky when dealing with C++ code. Very often I'll run into compilation problems that can be solved by rebuilding the project index or, shockingly, closing and then reopening the project.)

Answer (score 0):

I normally declare templates as below.

```
template <class T> struct Node ;
```

you have used

```
template class LinkedList<int> ;
```